# Setting up domain name for google apps domain and google app engine appplication

Tags: google-app-engine, domains, web-hosting, godaddy

I have deployed a app or a static web page on comingsoonjoineventus.appspot.com, when the users click joinevenuts.com they should be redirected to the appspot link. But its redirecting to google sites home page of the domain. I check the domain settings in both godaddy and also google domain cpanel. I am not able to figure it out. 
kindly help me in this regard

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html) documents how to set up a custom domain for your App Engine app. If you're seeing a sites page instead, that may be mapped to your www subdomain; you need to delete that mapping and add the one described in the doc.